# How to serialize 3rd party library property using MessagePack?

Tags: c#, msgpack

I would like to serialize property from the 3rd party object.
Let say I have:

```
        var pp = new Point3D(0,0,0);
        byte[] bytes = MessagePackSerializer.Serialize(pp);
```

I don't have access to to Point3D, so I can not mark it as [MessagePackObject]. For example with Protobuf I can create surrogate object and add it to RuntimeTypeModel like this:

```
 RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(Point3D), false).SetSurrogate(typeof(ProtoPoint3D));
```

So when serializer encounters Point3D object, it knows how to deal with it, is something like this possible with MessagePack Serializer (https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp)?